# Multiple quote symbols in HTML code, Flask project

Tags: html

I am creating a flask project and I have to write this in my html:

`onclick="location.href="/article/{{ article["id"] }}""`

But I need three separate sets of quotes to do it, is there anyway to insert something like backslash quote in python?

I've tried using `""` and `''`, also using `\"` and `\'` but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Try using `&quot`, see https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

Comment: Slightly OT, why are you using an onclick just to navigate, why not a plain `<a href=.. >`?